# How to force a file to download in-app instead of showing up in the default browser

Tags: android, webview, webclient

I created an Android application with WebView, but the only problem I am facing is that files are opening in the default browser instead of downloading.

This is the WebActivity code:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView01);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient()
    {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        findViewById(R.id.webView01).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


});     
    webView.loadUrl("domain");
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
    }); 

}


public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

 @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
     webView.goBack();
     return true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser app is opening because that's the appropriate app to handle `Intent`s holding a URL as their data, which is what you're using in your `DownloadListener`.


If you don't want the browser to fire up, open up an `InputStream` with the URL from your `DownloadListener` and fetch the bytes from the file yourself.

```
public void saveUrl(final String filename, final String urlString)
    throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
   BufferedInputStream in = null;
   FileOutputStream fout = null;
   try {
       in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
       fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

       final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
       int count;
       while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
          fout.write(data, 0, count);
       }
   } finally {
       if (in != null) {
           in.close();
       }
       if (fout != null) {
           fout.close();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - i tried Inputstream but again its opening in a new browser can you please provide the code

Comment: @user3566830 I added the code to save a file from a URL into a file to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the code but still it doesn't work i added the code right after
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

and before public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,

can you please be more specific where to add the code

Comment: @user3566830 Call `saveUrl` from `onDownloadStart` and remove the `Intent` stuff.

Comment: it gives a lot of errors in the code i delete Intent and call saveUrl from onDownloadStart can you provide a source i mean with the change in complete code i place above - it will be a big help still thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Cookies, sessions, ssl certificates?